# Is C++ value of this guaranteed?

Tags: c++, this

Consider I have a class Foo (that does not have its & operator overloaded) is the address obtained from the & operator of this class guaranteed to have the same value as its `this` pointer?

In the code below is equalPointer guaranteed to return true?
Are there any cases where it could return false (e.g. when considering multiple inheritance)?

```
class Foo
{
  bool equalPointer(const Foo * f} { return f==this; }
}
Foo f;
f.equalPointer(&f);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is one of memory layout. The standard doesn't guarantee much about memory layout, in particular it doesn't guarantee that no offset exists between a derived and a base class...

For example:

```
class Foo: public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
  virtual ~Foo();
};
```

Because `boost::noncopyable` doesn't have a `virtual` method, in gcc `(void*)(Foo*)&f` and `(void*)(boost::noncopyable*)&f` will have different values.

But this does not matter much in practice, because the compiler will perform the necessary adjustments. That is, if you only compare `Foo*` you should be fine and dandy...

... Apart that multiple inheritance might break this, if there are several `Foo` subobjects in your hierarchy.

On the other hand, you should be in one of two cases:

- either there is no hierarchy (no virtual) and then you can compare the address of objects as is
- or there is a hierarchy (and virtual method) and you use `dynamic_cast<void*>(&f)` to get the address of the complete object.

Therefore, as a template method, this would give:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
bool have_same_dynamic_location(T const& t, U const& u)
{
  return dynamic_cast<void*>(&t) == dynamic_cast<void*>(&u);
}
```

(which is only valid if both T and U have virtual methods)

Answer (score 2):

With the code in question?  Yes.

Are there constructs in which this is not so true?  Also yes.

But yes, a pointer to an instance of class X is always going to be equal to the 'this' pointer within class X.  Same can't be said of its base classes or derived classes.

Comment: Hmm. What happens when the function is defined as `template <typename T> bool equalPointer(T const* f)` and called as `f.equalPointer(&f)`? Is `f == this` guaranteed now? Offset correction shouldn’t occur then, right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

The pointer of `f` is the same, and it gets passed to `f::equalPointer`...